# URL Mapping to Method in Spring without annotations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I was using spring annotations to map url to method, as shown in below code.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/dashboard.htm" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dashboard(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
       .....
       return "success";
    } 

}
```

I have removed spring annotations by spring xml.

Previously I was accessing method using 
**localhost:8888/admin/dashboard.htm** url.

Now without annotations I need to use **localhost:8888/home/dashboard.htm** url to access method. I am using Controller Class Name HandlerMapping now.

What i need is, i want to access dashboard method using previous url **localhost:8888/admin/dashboard.htm** without annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` (or take a look`ControllerBeanNameHandlerMapping`) described in [Spring 2.5](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/reference/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping), which seems to do, what you want. But Why would anyone want that?

Comment: I am using MultiactionController. How can i map multiple url's with one controller.? is it possible.?